# Python: pyximporting a pyx that depends on a native library

Tags: python, cython

My pyx depends upon a native library

How can I [`pyximport.install()`](http://docs.cython.org/src/userguide/source_files_and_compilation.html#id1) it?  The auto-build in pyxinstall doesn't know to link with the native library, so the build fails...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can still export the correct LDFLAGS / CFLAGS before doing your pyximport.install() :

```
from os import environ
environ['CFLAGS'] = '-I/path/to/my/custom/lib'
environ['LDFLAGS'] = '-Lpath/to/my/custom/lib -lcustomlib'
import pyximport
pyximport.install()
```

However, pyximport should be used only in debug case. Prefer the setup.py method !

Comment: Not verified by Me, but wish I'd had this before I gave up on it all.

Comment: Regards, setup.py, I'm rather inclined to think pyximport would be infinitely preferable to me than setup.py which is a pain to develop and debug code with

Answer (score 5):

You can also specify build flags using a .pyxbld file.

For example, if you are trying to build **yourmodule.pyx**, simply place the following **yourmodule.pyxbld** file in the same directory as your pyx file:

```
def make_ext(modname, pyxfilename):
    from distutils.extension import Extension
    ext = Extension(name = modname,
        sources=[pyxfilename],
        extra_compile_args=['-I/path/to/my/custom/lib'],
        extra_link_args=['-Lpath/to/my/custom/lib', '-lcustomlib'])
    return ext

def make_setup_args():
    return dict(script_args=["--verbose"])
```